# Getting Index from RadioButtons(None are selected) inside RadioGroup from Value

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I was wondering how to get the index of radiobutton inside of radiogroup. 
The problem is that i get from API a Value(Apple, Banana, PineApple,etc), and I have the RadioButtons ready, named Apple, Banana, PineApple. How can I get the index of RB, so I can fill out the correct one. 
I know how to get the index, text, etc. if you select one from radiobutton but not if nothing is selected and i need to get an index based on text.
Instead of 
`radioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));`
it would be `rgTipPonudbe.getRadioButtonId("Apple")` and it should return the index of that radiobutton. I hope you understand my question. If not i'll try to explain it as best as i can.

Comment: I guess switch-case is your best option here.

Comment: Doubt it, because some radiobuttons are created dynamically and it is not very practical, for code maintaince :/. Any other ideas?